# Subtracting two Feature Collections in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, change-detection, feature-collection

I have two feature collections (before and after) that I want to subtract in Earth Engine. Each Feature Collection has an NDVI band computed, `BF_NDVI` for the before Image and `AF_NDVI` for the after collection.

I have written the function below from (Line 217) but it returns an error in `Line 229: Object is not callable`.

Any ideas on how I can solve this to get the resulting difference feature collection for export?

```
//Positive difference image indicates NDVI loss in the after invasion image
print('Difference_Image', difference)

//Extract before mean NDVI value
var bfMean = beforeCollectionMeans.select('BF_NDVI').first();

print('Before_Mean_NDVI', bfMean)

//Extract after mean NDVI value
var afMean = afterCollectionMeans.select('AF_NDVI').first();

print('After_Mean_NDVI', afMean)

//Get the difference mean NDVI value
var df = function(feature) {
  var diff = feature(bfMean).subtract(afMean)
  return diff;
}

var dfMean = invasionbuffer.map(df);

print('Difference_Mean_NDVI', dfMean)
```

The link to the full script; https://code.earthengine.google.com/ca15125c7b699144a04fd16fd76fd312

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Shiraz try this function I think it can help you..

```
var filter = ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.equals({
    leftField: 'doy',
    rightField: 'doy'
  }),
  ee.Filter.equals({
    leftField: 'OBJECTID',
    rightField: 'OBJECTID'
  })
);
  
// var filter = ee.Filter.equals({leftField:'doy', rightField:'doy'})
var join = ee.Join.saveFirst('match')
var merged_all = join.apply(before_zonal_value,after_zonal_value,  filter)

// print(merged_all,"merged_all")

// Build final collection
var merged = merged_all.map(function(feat){
  var match = ee.Feature(feat.get('match'))
  var after = ee.Number(match.get('Mean_NDVI')) 
  var before = ee.Number(feat.get('Mean_NDVI'))
  var diff = before.subtract(after)
  var feture = match.set('Bef_Mean_NDVI', before)
            .set('Aft_Mean_NDVI', after)
            .set('Dif_Mean_NDVI', diff)
  var properties = feture.propertyNames()          
  var selectProperties = properties.filter(ee.Filter.neq('item', "Mean_NDVI"))
  return feture.select(selectProperties)          
})  
  

print(merged,"merged")
```

full code [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/4ab38457d2aeaf14e9303cb4c4adbc39)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, subtract method is not included in **ee.Feature** or **ee.FeatureCollection** objects. So, your function has not sense and, it is not clear what do you want to do. For instance, as BF_NDVI and AF_NDVI are the only properties of **bfMean** and **afMean** Feature Collections, I think you could set **dfMean** as property in **invasionbuffer** Feature Collection. However, modifying your script as follows (for avoiding 'Object is not callable' error):

```
//Positive difference image indicates NDVI loss in the after invasion image
print('Difference_Image', difference);

//Extract before mean NDVI value
var bfMean = beforeCollectionMeans.select('BF_NDVI');

print('Before_Mean_NDVI (bfMean)', bfMean);

var bfMean_list = bfMean.toList(bfMean.size());

//Extract after mean NDVI value
var afMean = afterCollectionMeans.select('AF_NDVI');

print('After_Mean_NDVI (afMean)', afMean);

var afMean_list = afMean.toList(afMean.size());

var count = invasionbuffer.size();

//Get the difference mean NDVI value
var list = ee.List.sequence(0, count.subtract(1));

var ndvi_values = list.map(function (ele) {
  
  var bf_m = ee.Feature(ee.List(bfMean_list).get(ele)).get('BF_NDVI');
  var af_m = ee.Feature(ee.List(afMean_list).get(ele)).get('AF_NDVI');
  
  var dfMean = ee.Number(bf_m).subtract(ee.Number(af_m));
  
  return [bf_m, af_m];       
});

print("ndvi_values", ndvi_values);
```

one of differences cannot be produced because one of list values is null; as it can be observed in red rectangle of following image.

[image]

Complete code is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f1b23945facf7879085bd24573e2d558).

Comment: thanks for modifying the script to solve the error. What I'm aiming at is getting that the difference values by subtracting the af_m from bf_m, as a feature collection for export to CSV. These are resulting values from this expression in the code;  **var dfMean = ee.Number(bf_m).subtract(ee.Number(af_m))** Right now the script returns a **list of the bf_m & af_m values**. Calculating and returning the **difference** of these two values is the goal. Thanks for taking the time to look into it. Much appreciated